# Error Inside Of Visual Studio 2012 - " '.' or '(' expected "

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [GUID]
      ,[Ticket_Number]
      ,[Created_At]
      ,[Changed_At]
      ,[Priority]
      ,[Department]
      ,[Ticket_Type]
      ,[Category]
      ,[SubCategory]
      ,[Second_Category]
      ,[Third_Category]
      ,[ZZARN]
      ,[Categorization_Hash_Key]
      ,[ZZAID]
      ,[Work_Order]
      ,[Contact_Type]
      ,[Action]
      ,[BPartner_Key]
      ,[PFT]
      ,[Ticket_Status_Code]
      ,[Ticket_Status]
      ,[Audit_Key]
  FROM [CorporateDWTest].[dbo].[SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned]
```

& Design:
http://i40.tinypic.com/2ufvshz.png

Ya i deleted everything else, if someone has any idea what the guy who posted an answer refers to in reference to my tables column name design and structure please feel free to answer.

Class definition (That is inside of the Model1.Context.CS(.edmx)):

```
public DbSet<SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned> SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned { get; set; }
```

---

```
namespace CorporateDWTesting
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class CRM_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned
    {
        public byte[] GUID { get; set; }
        public string Ticket_Number { get; set; }
        public decimal Created_At_UTC { get; set; }
        public decimal Changed_At_UTC { get; set; }
        public string Priority { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Municipality { get; set; }
        public string Ticket_Type { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string SubCategory { get; set; }
        public string Address_Number { get; set; }
        public string Street1 { get; set; }
        public string Street2 { get; set; }
        public string Contact_Type { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public string BPartner_Key { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PFT { get; set; }
        public string Ticket_Status_Code { get; set; }
        public string Ticket_Status { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Due_Date_UTC { get; set; }
        public int Audit_Key { get; set; }

        public virtual Dim_Audit Dim_Audit { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Dim_Audit:

```
namespace CorporateDWTesting
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Dim_Audit
    {
        public Dim_Audit()
        {
            this.Business_Partner_Stage = new HashSet<Business_Partner_Stage>();
            this.CRM_Ticket_Transaction_Stage = new HashSet<CRM_Ticket_Transaction_Stage>();
            this.CRM_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned = new HashSet<CRM_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned>();
            this.Dim_Audit1 = new HashSet<Dim_Audit>();
            this.Dim_Categorization = new HashSet<Dim_Categorization>();
            this.Dim_Collection_Type = new HashSet<Dim_Collection_Type>();
            this.Dim_Municipality = new HashSet<Dim_Municipality>();
            this.Dim_Response_Team = new HashSet<Dim_Response_Team>();
            this.Dim_Ticket = new HashSet<Dim_Ticket>();
            this.Fact_Service_Units = new HashSet<Fact_Service_Units>();
            this.Fact_Service_Units1 = new HashSet<Fact_Service_Units>();
            this.Fact_Ticket_Processing = new HashSet<Fact_Ticket_Processing>();
            this.Fact_Ticket_Processing1 = new HashSet<Fact_Ticket_Processing>();
            this.Initial_Categories = new HashSet<Initial_Categories>();
        }

        public int Audit_Key { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Parent_Audit_Key { get; set; }
        public string Table_Name { get; set; }
        public string Package_Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> Package_GUID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Package_Version_Major { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Package_Version_Minor { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Execution_Start_Time { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Execution_End_Time { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Extract_Row_Count { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Insert_Row_Count { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Update_Row_Count { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Error_Row_Count { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Table_Initial_Row_Count { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Table_Final_Row_Count { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Table_Max_Surrogate_Key { get; set; }
        public string Table_Max_Business_Key { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Processing_Successful { get; set; }
        public string Error_Code { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Business_Partner_Stage> Business_Partner_Stage { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CRM_Ticket_Transaction_Stage> CRM_Ticket_Transaction_Stage { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CRM_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned> CRM_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Dim_Audit> Dim_Audit1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Dim_Audit Dim_Audit2 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Dim_Categorization> Dim_Categorization { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Dim_Collection_Type> Dim_Collection_Type { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Dim_Municipality> Dim_Municipality { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Dim_Response_Team> Dim_Response_Team { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Dim_Ticket> Dim_Ticket { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Fact_Service_Units> Fact_Service_Units { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Fact_Service_Units> Fact_Service_Units1 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Fact_Ticket_Processing> Fact_Ticket_Processing { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Fact_Ticket_Processing> Fact_Ticket_Processing1 { get; set; }
        public virtual GIS_Collection_Stage GIS_Collection_Stage { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Initial_Categories> Initial_Categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you place a breakpoint on that rule. What is the value of `SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned` inside of the `context` object?

Comment: if I place a breakpoint on the statement that causes the error the error still shows, and if I hover over context within that statement it says "local variable mydb context"

Comment: Can you show us the `CorporateDWTestEntities1` class as well? since that seems to be your `context`

Comment: Both blocks of code are missing a closing bracket for the outer method, is that a typo?

Comment: there is nothing to show, I set it up as an ado.net edmx data model that I named CorporateDWTestEntities1. I just reference it. I can screenshot my edmx's? or is there anything else I can provide?

Comment: What happens if you leave only the faulty line and comment all others?

Comment: it fails. the same error code. Vice Versa - it runs successfully

Comment: The only thing I can think of is SQL doesn't like your table name for some reason, are you able to change it to something else? Maybe it's the `Cleaned` part as you already have a similar table name that works fine.

Comment: please post SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned  class definition.. the problem is there!

Comment: Done. and I will attempt to change the table name now James!

Comment: does anybody see anything or has everyone given up lol

Comment: Can you add the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: What is the database name for the `SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned` entity?

Comment: yes just a second! & the name of the database for SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned is CorporateDWTest

Comment: the entities name is CorporateDWTestEntities2

Comment: And the table's name?

Comment: just tried deleting the older edmx thats why it says 2

Comment: stacktrace:http://i40.tinypic.com/ofstvc.png

Comment: The tables name? inside ssms is(was) SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned , now its SRS_Ticket_Transaction_CLEAN - just to see if it was a name thing but no it wasn't

Comment: @user3032552 I kinda meant rename it to something *other* than `_CLEANED` (regardless of case). However, if it's not the name itself then I would stab a guess at the column name length? Try renaming it to something smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be related to a table column name. Make sure that the columns of your database table have safe names (for example, not the same as the name of a SQL data type name).

If you post the table's structure, probably that's going to be obvious.

Reference: [ParseException when adding orderBy attribute to linqdatasource control](http://forums.asp.net/t/1190427.aspx)

**UPDATE**

In order to solve your issue, rename the `GUID` property / column.

The stack trace, which pointed to

```
    BatchExtensions.Delete[TEntity](IQueryable'1 source)
```

and later on to [this method](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/Source/EntityFramework.Extended/Dynamic/DynamicQueryable.cs):

```
    public static IQueryable 
        Select(this IQueryable source, string selector, params object[] values)
```

indicates that the exception is raised in the [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/tree/master/Source) library.

You'll have to avoid naming your properties as one of the following predefined types (case insensitive):

```
static readonly Type[] predefinedTypes = {
    typeof(Object),
    typeof(Boolean),
    typeof(Char),
    typeof(String),
    typeof(SByte),
    typeof(Byte),
    typeof(Int16),
    typeof(UInt16),
    typeof(Int32),
    typeof(UInt32),
    typeof(Int64),
    typeof(UInt64),
    typeof(Single),
    typeof(Double),
    typeof(Decimal),
    typeof(DateTime),
    typeof(TimeSpan),
    typeof(Guid),
    typeof(Math),
    typeof(Convert)
};
```

Comment: Im not sure if I understand the example.

Comment: I go into ssms, I click the table thats giving me the error, rename it so it doesn't resemble any column names, save, update the edmx?

Comment: Just post the table's structure in your question's body, we'll spot the problem over there.

Comment: One more piece is needed in order to solve the puzzle: could you post the class definition for `SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned`?

Comment: The class definition for `SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned`: in your code, right-click on the type, then `Go to definition`.

Comment: I did that and I posted the statement above

Comment: No, that's not the class definition, it's a property of the context class. The definition should be under `Model1.tt` in your VS project. The file should be named _SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned.cs_.

Comment: Found it! Posting it now.

Comment: Please also post the definition of the `Dim_Audit` class.

Comment: Dont tell me you're stumped :(

Comment: I really, really appreciate you taking the time to assist me. Can I ask why it didnt like the name GUID ? What else was named GUID ? How did you solve this?